# Combine if statement conditions for button clicked and "enter" key pressed on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 functions in jQuery, both of which commit the same AJAX function when the input form's submit button is clicked or "Enter" key is pressed on the form. I have 2 identical forms with id 'reserve_email_1' and 'reserve_email_2'.

How do I combine the conditions of the if statement, so I don't need to repeat the same AJAX call for 4 times?

Thanks so much,

Major function:

```
$(function(){

  $('#subscribe_1').click(function(){ 

     $("#subscribe_1").text('Sending……');

    var email = $('#reserve_email_1').val();
    var name = $('#reserve_requirement_1').val();

      var regex_email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

      if (regex_email.test(email)||email.match(/^\d+$/))
      {

      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: base_url + "interview/reserve",
          data:{email : email, interview_id: interview_id, name: name}, 
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data,status){
            if(data.state == 'succ')
            {
              $("#subscribe_1").text(data.msg+'！');
              $('#reserve_email_1').attr('readonly', true);
            }
            else
            {
              $("#subscribe_1").text(data.msg);  
            }
    }
      });

  }

  else
  {
  $("#subscribe_1").text('');
  }

  }); 
 });
 //end of subscribe part 1
```

and for the condition where the user press 'enter', I simply modify the top part to:

```
 //beginning of subscribe on subscribe page part 1 with enter key
 $(function(){

  $("#reserve_email_1").bind('keyup', function(event){ 
   if(event.keyCode == 13){ 

     event.preventDefault();
```

and the rest remains the same. But I'm having trouble combining these 2 conditions ("click button" and "press enter") so I don't have to rewrite the whole ajax action again.

The situation is further complicated by the fact that I have another identical form called reserve_email_2, which calls the exact same function.

Thanks so much,

P.S. I posted this question earlier but didn't get an answer. As a result, I cleaned up my phrases and hoping it would be easier to solve.

Comment: To clarify, do you want the event triggered only after the user performs both the actions, or only on the first one

Comment: I would like the event to trigger either when the user click on the button or press enter on the form.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. Why don't you just make a function containing the AJAX code, and call it from both event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to duplicate your code. First of all you should not use click event for form submission, there is dedicated form event called `onsubmit`. The benefit is obvious - it will fire both on submit button press and on Enter key press. So in your form would be:

```
<form class="subscribe-form">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="subscribe" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn-subscribe">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS becomes:

```
$('.subscribe-form').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var $btn = $(this).find('.btn-subscribe');
    $btn.text('Sending……');

    var $email = $('.subscribe');
    var email = $email.val();
    var name = $('.requirement').val();

    var regex_email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (regex_email.test(email) || email.match(/^\d+$/)) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + "interview/reserve",
            data: {
                email: email,
                interview_id: interview_id,
                name: name
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status) {
                if (data.state == 'succ') {
                    $btn.text(data.msg + '！');
                    $email.attr('readonly', true);
                } else {
                    $btn.text(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });

    } else {
        $btn.text('Send');
    }

});
```

So it will automatically work for all forms with `.subscribe-form` class. To make it reusable add the same class to email field like `class="subscribe"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would work perfect in other cases I guess. The problem for me is that I'm using Bootstrap, and for some weird reason using <form> would mess up the entire layout of the section. So do we have an option to not use an alternative of the form onsubmit function?

Comment: You should use proper approaches. Using onsubmit is how it should be done. If you choose your own way good luck, but you have already seen what it leads you to, code duplicates and lower code quality. If you have problem with HTML when you use form, then this is another issue. It should not affect JS quality.